# How to use void*?

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-arrays

Why does this code use `& (*p)[i]`?

```
typedef void* sir;
int main(){

    sir *p;    
    int x[10],i;    
    for(i = 0;i < 10;i++)
        x[i] = i;
    p = &x;
    for(i = 0;i < 10;i++)
        printf("%d ",&(*p)[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of `sir`?

Comment: @MikeCAT `typedef void sir`...poor formatting

Comment: Then `p` has type `void**`.

Comment: The only way to "use" `void *` is to cast to or from a different pointer type (as you do at `p = &x`). *Dereferencing* `void*` -- as you do in that `printf()` statement -- is undefined behaviour. The purpose of `void *` is to act as a "generic" pointer type for functions like `memcpy()`.

Comment: [Compiler warnings](http://goo.gl/D4MNKg): `dereferencing 'void *' pointer`, and also, on the same line, `format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'sir {aka void *}' [-Wformat=]`.  It looks to me like it's a bad way to write `(i + *p)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin No, `p[i]`  have type `void*`.

Comment: "Why does this code use `& (*p)[i]`?" To invoke *undefined behavior*? Unary `&` operator will return a pointer, which `%d` won't accept.

Comment: Pointer aritimetic on `void*` is not allowed by the standard although GCC accepts it.

Comment: @MikeCAT thanks, must be sleepy. the same applies to the void, there are just not enough stars out tonight...

Comment: Retracting close vote, as @machine_1 gave a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you typedef'ed `sir` as`void *`,so when you write `sir *p`,you are declaring `p` to be of type `void**`,a double void pointer.Try instead to declare `p` as `sir p`,and to print the elements of the array,use the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef void* sir;

int main(void)
{
    sir p;
    int x[10], i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        x[i] = i;
    p = &x;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%d ", *((int *)p + i));
    return 0;
}
```

Note: A void pointer cannot be de-referenced without a cast of the appropriate type,`int` in this case.Also pointer arithmetic is not allowed on void pointers.

To print the addresses of the elements of the array instead of the elements themselves, use :

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("%p\n", (void *)((int *)p + i));
}
```

Comment: Do not use `%x` to print address, or you invoke *undefined behavior*. use `%p` and cast the address to print to `void*`.